# How do I know how long my socket.io connection lags by?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, timing

I'm making something that is timing specific and need to know exactly how many ms something being sent over socket.io lags by. And if it lags by say 10ms then I would need to delay my timing logic by 10ms so that the client appears to have timed the action correctly.

Comment: You want to know how long a packets travel takes before you even sent it?

Comment: I want to know how long it has taken after it arrives.

Comment: It's tough to say without more info about your usecase. TCP/IP doesn't really give you any guarantee time-wise. For all you know, it could take 5ms to send one packet and 30s to send the next one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The developer behind Socket.io just came out with a package that should help.

https://github.com/guille/latency-io